# Millions of tables on Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery for ~5 billion rows that can be partitioned on ~1 million keys.

Since our queries are usually by partition key, is it possible to create ~1 million tables (1 table / key) to limit the total number of bytes processed?

We also need to query all of the data together at times, which is easy to do by putting it all in one table, but I'm hoping to use the same platform for partitioned analysis as bulk analytics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That might work, but partitioning your table this finely is highly discouraged. You might be better off partitioning your data into a smaller number of tables, say 10 or 100, and querying just the one(s) you need.

What do I mean by discouraged? First, each of those million tables will get charged a minimum of 10 MB for storage. So you'll get charged for 9 TB of storage, when you likely have a lot less data than that. Second, you'll likely hit rate limits when you try to create that many tables. Third, managing a million tables is very tricky; the BigQuery UI will likely not be much help. Fourth, you'll make engineers on the BigQuery exceedingly grumpy, and they'll start trying to figure out whether we need to raise the minimum size for tables.

Also, if you do want to sometimes query all of your data, partitioning this finely is likely going to make things difficult for you, unless you are willing to store your data multiple times. You can only reference 1000 tables in a query, and each one you reference causes you to take a performance hit.